# time taken to sum up all the numbers in binary search tree that lie between two numbers

Tags: algorithm, search

Suppose we have a balanced binary search tree T holding n numbers. We are given two 
numbers L and H and wish to sum up all the numbers in T that lie between L and H. Suppose 
there are m such numbers in T.Can someone explain how to calculate the absolute value of the time taken to compute the sum..?

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave you to work out the full details, but here's a start. The algorithm will go:

1. Find the smallest number in the tree that's greater than `L`. You can do that in log time.
2. Walk the tree, each time moving to the next largest, and adding it to a running total.
3. Stop when you reach a number that's at least `H`.

I've assumed that "lie between" means "strictly between", but you might want weak inequalities in steps 1 and 3.

Comment: thanks, nicely explained. And "lie between" means including L and H.But i had a doubt,that We are taking in account the time needed to search for L(i.e. log time) but we dont need to search for H.Why so?>

Comment: Because you'll find `H` (or the first one greater than `H`) as you walk the tree. You need to know where to start the walk, but after that, you just process elements in turn till you hit the other end. You could equally well do it from the other direction: find `H`, then walk backwards till you get to something that's smaller than `L`.